# Use a Mini Displayport cable to connect a Late 2013 rMBP to a 2009 iMac?

Tags: imac, macbook-pro, thunderbolt, displayport, target-display

Can I use a male to male Mini Displayport cable to connect a Late 2013 rMBP to a 2009 iMac?

I want to use the 2009 iMac as a secondary display for the rMBP.

Answer (score 3):

My late 2009 iMac works as an external display for my Early 2013 15" Retina MacBook Pro, and for my Mid 2014 15" Retina MacBook Pro, using [this cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00HNF0L2C). Both laptops have Thunderbolt; the iMac does not have Thunderbolt.

I don't have a Late 2013 Retina MacBook to test, but it seems reasonable to assume it has the same compatibility. Apple also indicates DisplayPort cables work for the 2009 iMac.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204592